# Sequences; the binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find $A, B, C$ such that the expansion in ascending powers of $x$ of $A(1+x)^7 +B(1-2x)^5 +C(1-3x)^3$ begins with terms in $x^2$

I put $A+B+C=0$ and $ 7A -10B -9C=0$ to let $x^2$ be the first term in the expansion. So $A, B, C$ could be $-k, 16k, -17k$ or $k, 16k, -17k$ 
 or $-k/272, -k/17, k/16$ or $k/272, k/17, -k/16$

Does it mean $A, B ,C$ can be any of these.

Comment: For example $(1+x)^7=...+{7 \choose 5}x^{2}+...=...+21x^2+...$ and so on.

Comment: The answer gives A=k, B=16*k, C=-17*k for any value of k. What does it mean.

Comment: @abee99 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let apply for each term $$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^{n-k}y^k $$

to find the $x^2$ coefficient, then set the condition for A,B,C such that the condition is satisfied.